# stateless singleton in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to define a **"stateless singleton"** in JAVA-EE which can be accessed by multiple threads simultanously.

*By stateless I mean: the Bean-Instance has no fields.*

Which one should I use:

version 1:

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyStatelessSingleton {
..
}
```

version 2:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyStatelessSingleton {
..
}
```

version 3:

```
@javax.inject.Singleton
public class MyStatelessSingleton {
..
}
```

**By the way, I cannot see the benefit in having pooled "stateless instances" instead of one "stateless singleton bean".**

Comment: I dont think that matters

Comment: '@ApplicationScoped' is managed by servlet container while @javax.ejb.Singleton is managed by EJB-Container. Does it matter if client has no web session and only uses 'MyStatelessSingleton' within ejb-container?

Comment: Use the one that fits you.

Comment: By stateless you mean, that your Bean-Instance has no fields? Otherwise pooled stateless instances (@Stateless) can help you compared to Singletons without Concurrency Management

Comment: @aschoerk yes, bean instance has no fields, only method calls. Please, could you provide an example where an stateless instances (@Stateless) with instance field can help in compare to stateless Singletons? I guess, instance fields within stateless beans are always equal to all clients, the same as singleton stateless.

Comment: If you use a Stateless bean with fields. During one call to the bean, you can use the fields of the instance in a safe way, because during that call the instance belongs to your thread. This can help in avoiding long lists of parameters, if the bean-instance uses calls to other methods in the same bean. That might not be a beautiful solution, but it happens. In case of Singleton with deactivated ConcurrencyManagement, those fields are in danger of being manipulated by other threads. But you can use fields in such Singletons as well, if you define them ThreadLocal or handle them with Atomic....

Comment: @aschoerk good point: "This can help in avoiding long lists of parameters, if the bean-instance uses calls to other methods in the same bean." However, when another client uses that stateless bean after it is placed in the pool, then the client will inherit all these instance variables which are set by the previous client. Or?

Comment: I suppose so. Especially he cannot presume default values for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that matters. Its a singleton. It stateless/statefull nature will be only dictated by how you implement it. `ApplicationScoped` is my favorite here.

Comment: yes, I also tend to go with '@ApplicationScoped'. I cannot find any benefit in using "version 1".

Comment: By the way, I want to use the "stateless singleton"-pattern for a stateless DAO (typical JPA-CRUD where the entityManager is provided within method-parameters). So I guess, stateless singleton is better than using '@Stateless'.

Comment: But if bean is stateless/statefull matters only if you are using non-singleton beans as the container might juggle with instances during single process as it does not matter if it is the same exact instance of that bean. Singleton is always the same. Moreover statefull beans has its lifecyle. Its hardly to say there is lifecycle in singleton.

Comment: I only decided to go with "Singleton" instead of "Stateless" to save memory: because I dont want to inject new (stateless) instances or from a bunch of pooled instances on each injection. I dont need stateful beans and I dont need pooled instances. I cannot see the benefit in having pooled "stateless instances" instead of one "stateless singleton bean"